# Can anyone expalin the getPayout() for Roulette game in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js, roulette-wheel-selection

I am trying to understand the getPayout() in Roulette game code in solidity.
Can anyone explain me the calculation here?
And what does POPCNT_MULT, POPCNT_MASK and POPCNT_MODULO variable mean?

contract Roulette is Game {

```
uint8 private constant MODULO = 37;
uint256 private constant POPCNT_MULT =
    0x0000000000002000000000100000000008000000000400000000020000000001;
uint256 private constant POPCNT_MASK =
    0x0001041041041041041041041041041041041041041041041041041041041041;
uint256 private constant POPCNT_MODULO = 0x3F;

/// @notice Calculates the target payout amount.
/// @param betAmount Bet amount.
/// @param numbers The chosen numbers.
/// @return The target payout amount.
function _getPayout(uint256 betAmount, uint40 numbers)
    private
    pure
    returns (uint256)
{
    return
        (betAmount * MODULO) /
        (((numbers * POPCNT_MULT) & POPCNT_MASK) % POPCNT_MODULO);
}
```

}